# Windows 98 routing issue

Tags: nat, openwrt, masquerade

I have following network setup:

- Main router connecting to internet, with LAN address 192.168.1.254
- Secondary router connected to first router, with LAN address 192.168.2.1

I have two PC's connected to secondary router, one with Windows 7, another with Windows 98. Both can access the internet, but on Windows 98 i cannot connect directly to first router for some reason (or any other computer on 192.168.1.0/24 network). On Windows 7 everything works fine. What could be cause of that?

Note: secondary router is OpenWRT-converted access point.

Comment: Windows 98?  Are these on display in a museum? :-)

Comment: Kinda, I'm a collector of old hardware and operating systems. I'm setting up a gallery of those in my garage :)

Comment: Cool, glad you got it working

Comment: `Windows 98. Both can access the internet`. Please do not connect such a thing on the Internet.

Comment: @EsaJokinen actually i just needed to be able to connect to other pc's on 192.168.1.0, for file sharing and lan-party purposes ;) what's the problem with windows 98 having access to the internet though? especially behind 3 layers of nat ;D

Comment: NAT doesn't really help when the Windows 98 machine gets the malicious content from the Internet using outbound connections. At least do not surf the Internet.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I'm aware of the danger, I'm not planning using it for surfing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Turned out that the TCP/IP protocol on Dial-up card was set to static address on 192.168.1.0/24 network.